# How to resize Alpine Linux terminal in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, alpine-linux

Please help me with info, **how to resize terminal window** of Alpine Linux inside the VirtualBox so that it would fill all the host virtualbox window.

Alpine version: **virt-3.7.0** 
VirtualBox version: **5.2.12** (macOS host)

I've also installed *virtualbox-guest-additions* and *virtualbox-guest-modules-virthardened* with apk like this:

```
apk add virtualbox-guest-additions virtualbox-guest-modules-virthardened
```

But it still does not work.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming you're talking about the standard linux console, not a graphical terminal inside Xorg or Wayland.  That being the case:

### With extlinux bootloader

Alpine defaults to using extlinux when installed on a machine that's booted in BIOS mode.

You can set the terminal size by editing `/boot/extlinux.conf`:

1. Remove `nomodeset` from the line starting `APPEND`.
2. Add a `video=...` line at the end of the `APPEND` line, with the resolution you want.  For example, `video=1440x900`.
3. Reboot.

### With grub bootloader

Alpine defaults to grub when installed on a machine booted in EFI mode.

Edit `/etc/default/grub`:

1. Find the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line, and remove `nomodeset`.
2. Add these two lines:

   ```
   GRUB_GFXMODE=1440x900
   GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=1440x900
   ```
3. Run `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` as root (or use sudo if you have it set up).
4. Reboot

---

The virtualbox guest additions packages only provide support for Xorg video, and a few other things like shared folders.

Answer (score 3):

I installed with the following steps.

```
echo "http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories
apk update
apk upgrade --update-cache --available
apk add virtualbox-guest-additions
rc-update add virtualbox-guest-additions default
echo vboxpci    >> /etc/modules
echo vboxdrv    >> /etc/modules
echo vboxnetflt >> /etc/modules
```

This increases the display resolution.

Comment: didnt work for me